# XML text in Varchar(max) mysterious question mark

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, xml, vb.net

I have a function in a VB .NET  class library, which inserts XML text into a VARCHAR(MAX) column.
The column results in an extra "?" at the front of the data in the column. I do not want that character in my data.

The column data starts like :

```
  ?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Registration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"....
```

The insert function is :

```
INSERT INTO Table (Data) OUTPUT Inserted.ID VALUES (@Data)
```

The table has 2 columns, Data and ID.

Am I doing something wrong. The XML is created by the .Net XmlSerializer.

Thanks

Comment: If it looks like `XML`, quacks like `XML`, smells like `XML` ....... why on earth aren't you **storing** it in an `XML` column !???!!?!

Comment: Total guess, but is the XML encoded with a byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning?  Can you tell in the debugger whether the data getting inserted has this extra character (before it goes in the DB)?

Comment: Try NVARCHAR. You have something there.  It could even be a white space that is not in varchar.

Comment: @marc_s, in theory you are correct, but it's currently impossible in MSSQL to store XML along with its processing instruction, like in the example provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, all XML in SQL Server is in Unicode (UCS-2, to be precise), and data access libraries probably know that. So storing their output in `varchar` column isn't the best idea - you might run into various issues with implicit conversion, and such. Try switching the column data type to `nvarchar` and look whether it helped.

Second, it might be some mark bytes that are usually found in disk files stored in UTF-8. Since SQL Server doesn't support this encoding, these bytes might have been converted (again, implicitly) into something unreadable. Try something like this query:

```
select cast(substring(XMLField, 1, 10) as varbinary)
from dbo.MyTable;
```

It will show you ASCII codes for those characters, at least.

My best guess, however, would be to get rid of UTF-8 completely - the only way to store such data in SQL Server is via `varbinary` columns, but I doubt you will like the resulting overhead. Try switching to UTF-16 - it's backward compatible with UCS-2 (unless you deal in something truly exotique).

Answer (score 0):

Varchar can only hold characters in the ascii code page. My guess would be you have some unicode character at the beginning of that string.

Switch to nvarchar, you won't get rid of that initial character but you won't lose it either

Comment: That is not correct.  Varchar and char will use a 256 character code page such as Windows-1252 or CP-1252.

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulty with this using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`.  I also wanted the XML to be stored as a human-readable string (because of reasons).

Here's the code I used in case it is useful to someone:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.SomeRootType));
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
using var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
ser.Serialize(writer, myObjectModel);
var xml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

// format the XML
var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml);
var niceXmlForTheDB = doc.ToString();
```

Notes:

- Needs C# 8 for the `using` statements without the braces
- Doesn't *strictly* need `using` for `MemoryStream`, but hey...
- Can convert to VB if needed using one of the many online tools (you'll be used to if you code in VB!)
- This code should probably be in a try-catch which does something sensible if it fails!